# Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I have created One Filter Attribute

```cs
public class AuthFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthFilterAttribute()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

    }
}
```

I have registered this filter inside the `global.asax.cs`.

When I am trying to call my web API using *Postman* it is showing the error:

> Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'.

My project target framework is `4.6.1` and the `System.Net.Http` version is `4.2.0.0`

My API looks like this:

```cs
[AuthFilter]
public class ScheduleApiController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/schedules")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSchedules()
    {
    }
}
```

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions worked for me.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add the url with which your are trying to call from postman

Comment: I am trying to run in the local host Url is :http://localhost:54252/api/v1/schedules

Comment: Try removing [AuthFilter] .an make sure you have  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in WebApiConfig

Comment: You can also try the default help that is available when you create new web api project.Try accessing http://localhost:54252/help

Comment: when I am trying localhost:54252/help it is throwing exception Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMethod System.Web.Http.Description.ApiDescription.get_HttpMethod()'

Comment: Do you have this file also at this location:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib` If so, try deleting/renaming it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are you referencing a .NET Standard Library by any chance. I ran into this problem and solved it with a Binding Redirect:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was using Standard 2.0 for dlls and Framework 4.7 for web api.

Comment: Saved my bacon!

Comment: WTF why didn't publish wizard automatically added it in web.config?

Comment: After 6 hours this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable the auto-generate bindings.
Right Click on your project --> Properties --> Application

[Tick that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG3Dc.png)