# "Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I have written a simple custom Authorize attribute that is applied to several WebAPI methods. When I run in my localhost everything works as expected but when I move the binaries to a true web server I start getting the following error message:

> "Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'

If I remove my custom Authorize attribute everything works fine on both servers.

The full stack trace is:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'.","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","StackTrace":"   at MyApp.CustomAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
>    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"}
>
> The Custom Attribute (stripped down but behavior is the same) is:

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var authValue = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            return;
        }
}
}
```

The problem seems to be centered on the HttpActionContext Request property. If I try to get the value from that property it throws the above error. If I remark out that line it runs fine.

Any ideas?

*** Additional info ***
I am able to remove all code from the OnAuthorization method and simply return and it will throw the same error.

*** More ***
The error happens when I try to access the Request method of HttpActionContext.

Comment: are you having version mismatch or doing something crazy in your build?

Comment: Nothing crazy. But there may be some sort of version mismatch.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767979/method-not-found-system-net-http-httprequestmessage-system-web-http-controller/51422587)?

Comment: Check the solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451247/missing-method-in-system-web-http-
apicontroller-get-request

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451247/missing-method-in-system-web-http-
apicontroller-get-request

Answer (score 0):

This exception throw because some case your `actionContext` is null.

Change to

```
var authValue = actionContext != null ? actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization : null;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Same error as before.

Comment: Did you check null all for your actionContext?

Comment: I don't believe that the application even gets to that point before it errors out. It seems that it may have something to do with versioning in system files.

Comment: Like a direct dll reference instead of a solution/project reference?

Comment: did you try copy all dll in bin folder when you run in local to your server?

Comment: Yes copied all DLLs from local to server